# How to set the 4 corners X, Y coordinates value of a FabricJS image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

*I would like to set **aCoords** value of image. *(Corner coordinates)*
Through **setCoords** it updates values however it does not change the position of the image.*

```
        image?.set({
    'aCoords': {
        tl: new fabric.Point(0, 100),
        tr: new fabric.Point(0, 200),
        br: new fabric.Point(100, 200),
        bl: new fabric.Point(100, 200)
    }
})

     if(canvas) {
        console.log('render')
        image.setCoords()
        canvas.renderAll();
        canvas.requestRenderAll()
    }
```

Comment: hi Elvin, i think you came also on the issue tracker. You can't set aCoords those are private for fabric to set, and for you to read. What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: I have dynamic corner points, and I want to locate an image based on these corner points. 

İf I can not set aCords, how can I set exact position?

I have read a document, there are left, top, angleX, angleY, width, height and so on, properties. 

Is there any way to get (settable)  properties from aCoord values?

Comment: I think i solve this exact question for rects in the issue tracker in a fiddle. Was that you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example, that you could also find in the discussion area on the repo:

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/discussions/6834

The solution is geometric only, nothing that is specifically of fabric.JS

```js
// Canvas 2
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('c2');

  const aCoords = {
      tl: new fabric.Point(0, 100),
      tr: new fabric.Point(0, 200),
      br: new fabric.Point(100, 200),
      bl: new fabric.Point(100, 100)
  }
  
  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://weeblytutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Weebly-blogs-example.png', img => {
    const width = img.width;
    const height = img.height;
    img.set({
      left: aCoords.tl.lerp(aCoords.br).x,
      top: aCoords.tl.lerp(aCoords.br).y,
      scaleX: (aCoords.tl.distanceFrom(aCoords.tr)) / width,
      scaleY: (aCoords.tl.distanceFrom(aCoords.bl)) / height,
      angle: fabric.util.radiansToDegrees(Math.atan2(aCoords.tr.y - aCoords.tl.y, aCoords.tr.x - aCoords.tl.x)),
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
    })
    canvas2.add(img);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fabric@4.3.0/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c2" width="400" height="400" >
```